# download file from url with flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, url, pytube

I am working on a project to download youtube video by `pytube` module. I want to download a specific resolution video only when user click on button in html.

**How do I pass `pytube steam` to html and make downloadable button?**

**`app.py`**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
from ydownload import Ymate

app = Flask(__name__)
user_query = ''
input_value = ''
base_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='


#--------------------------------------------------
@app.route('/')
def youtube_link():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        link = 'e7BufAVwDiM'
        return render_template("main.html", input_value=base_url+link, user_query='ydownload', ymate=Ymate(link))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**`main.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Youtube</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default m-b-0">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="div-form">
                        <div class="hero hero-homepage">
                            <h1 class="hero-header">Download Unlimited Videos From Youtube</h1>
                            <div class="ads_banner m-t m-b">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <form class="form-inline form-search" action=""
                                    id="search-form" method="get" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form">
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" value="{{ input_value }}" id="txt-url"
                                        name="txt" type="text" placeholder="Search or Paste link here.....">
                                    <button type="submit" value="Start" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-lg"
                                        style="color: white;">
                                        <span class="hidden-xs">Search </span>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <p class="small">You are accepting our
                                        <a class="active" href="" target="_blank">
                                            Terms of Use
                                        </a> by using our services.
                                    </p>
                                    <img class="hidden" id="loading_bar"
                                        src="" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% if 'ydownload' in user_query %}
                    <div class="container-fluid" id="query-response">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5" id="thumbnail-div">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <img src="{{ ymate.title_img_url()['img_url'] }}">
                                    <p><b>{{ ymate.title_img_url()['title'] }}</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-7" id="query-table">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="video_tab"><b>Video</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="audio_tab"><b>Audio</b></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="video">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Resolution</th>
                                            <th>FileSize</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {% for video in ymate.video_list() %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ video }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ ymate.video_list()[video][0] }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="/" download="" class="btn btn-success">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                                                    <span class="btn-hidden">Download</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>


                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="audio" style="display: none">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>FileType</th>
                                            <th>FileSize</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {% for audio in ymate.audio_list() %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ audio }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ ymate.audio_list()[audio][0] }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="{{ ymate.audio_list()[audio][1] }}" class="btn btn-success">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                                                    <span class="btn-hidden">Download</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`ydownload.py`**

```
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist
from pprint import pprint
from math import floor, log, pow

class Ymate:
    def __init__(self, url):
        main_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={url}'
        self.video_ = YouTube(main_url)
        self.vid_steam = self.video_.streams

    def title_img_url(self):
        items = {   "img_url": self.video_.thumbnail_url,
                    "title": self.video_.title
                    }
        return items

    @staticmethod
    def convert_size(size_bytes):
        if size_bytes == 0:
            return "0B"
        size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
        i = int(floor(log(size_bytes, 1024)))
        p = pow(1024, i)
        s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
        return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])

    def audio_list(self):
        audio_steam = self.vid_steam.filter(type='audio').order_by('abr').asc()
        audio_dict = {}
        for counter in range(len(audio_steam)):
            audio_dict.update({
                audio_steam[counter].abr: [self.convert_size(audio_steam[counter].filesize_approx), audio_steam[counter]]
                })
        return audio_dict

    def video_list(self):
        video_steam = self.vid_steam.filter(type='video').order_by('resolution').asc()
        vid_res = []
        res_counter = 0
        video_dict = {}
        for count in range(len(video_steam)):
            if video_steam[count].resolution not in vid_res:
                vid_res.append(video_steam[count].resolution)
                vid_list = video_steam.filter(resolution=vid_res[res_counter]).first()
                res_counter += 1
                video_dict.update({
                    vid_list.resolution: [self.convert_size(vid_list.filesize_approx), vid_list]
                })
        return video_dict
```

**I want to learn how can I iterate `pytube.steam` into html and make a button to download specify resolution video by the help of python or flask!**

Answer (score 0):

In the flask file try adding a post method. This would understand when a button/form is submitted and can act appropriately. [Here's](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods) some info to get you started.

Comment: I want to downoad youtube video (specific resolution) through `pytube module` only when i click on button in thml tag~

Comment: Understood. The post I included goes through the process of setting up an html button that sends a request to your server at which point you can handle that request accordingly.

Comment: Can you please eleborate?

Comment: I am new to flask.

Comment: The website provides all the information. When you press a button it will tell your code that a button was pressed. Then you can download it after the code gets that message.

Comment: I also want to open [`save file option`](https://ibb.co/dbS2kjF) whenever I click on button and want to [visually see](https://ibb.co/5WR4BWN) download in my chrome browser not in the background.

Comment: I mean that let browser to handle downloading progress.

Comment: Well there is no way to avoid the server doing the downloading. The speed depends on the persons computer. If you want to see the download you could check the flask documentation or add a custom HTML page.

Comment: how to do i make it happen?

Comment: please, help me

Comment: there is a website `y2mate.com`. I want to make some look like [this](https://www.y2mate.com/youtube/h3cgHyusc5s)

Comment: and there download `<a href="https://dl200.y2mate.com/?file=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" </a>`

Comment: how can I generate this `href` **downloading link**

Comment: It seems you want to download from a link. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) link teaches you how to get a downloading link through the HTML. If this helped in anyway feel free to mark the answer as correct. Also if this doesn't makes sense I would suggest going through the flask documentation. This way you get a better feel for things because what you're asking has server and front end components.

Comment: can you make me understand?

Comment: can i do that with the help of `youtube-dl`?

Comment: Okay your views are very confusing. Would you like to this solely in python. If so did you go through the flask documentation like I said? I could give it to you on a silver platter but you won't learn. Before you embark on this project take the time to learn the intricacies of flask. That will help you the most. If this post led you in the right directions feel free to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: what do you mean by **solely in python**?

Comment: I went through whole flask documentation not only once but many times but nothing is helpfull.

Comment: They (flask doc) didn't talk about what I want.

Comment: please can you demonstarate me!

Comment: You can provide me any link  from where did you learn.

Comment: I am having url of videos and play smoothly but their audio does not (exist.)[https://ibb.co/WWLnKrz]

Comment: and audio work on only one resolution type of a video.

Comment: why is this happening?

Comment: I even tried changing its url header:                                              
`url.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/json' 
                                                                                                                                                             url.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;'`

Comment: Ok. So you want to download a video by the click of a button right? So using requests you can do something like.  ||. means enter ````@app.route('/',methods = ["POST,"GET"]) || def index():|| if request.method=='POST': || (script to download video)|| return render_template('download.html')``` That provides a basic way to get a button press. That should answer you question. Again I suggest learning Flask itself as a whole instead of pruning it to look for what you want. Maybe start with a small project that teaches you how to handle posts.

Comment: This project is VERY big, so I would suggest learning flask first.